# Archiving data between databases

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have written an application that archives data from two views within a SQL Server database to different tables in another SQL Server database in Java using JDBC driver 4. The thing I'm concerned about is the performance of the application.

It takes about 13 minutes to archive 20 messages together with its attachments (only name and link information.) in total, the data consists of 20 columns.

Column overview:

```
smallint(6)
datetime
int(11)
varchar(255)
varchar(100)
varchar(100)
varchar(100) 
text
int(11) 

int(11)
varchar(255)
varchar(255)
int(11)
```

Can someone please give me pointers as to how make the performance better?
And tell me if the runtime given above is acceptable or not. (I know this depends on the situation, the application is meant to be a POC).

**Things I checked out (EDIT)**

I've read some posts on auto-commit, saying that you could disable it to improve performance. I first checked the Java tuts to find the following link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit

In the article commit is explained. When I check the for loop in one of the examples commit is used at the end of each update, which is logical. But what is the difference between using auto-commit and committing after every insert?

I'm using prepared statements do to the inserts to the archive database.

**Information after using debugger**

I have used the eclipse debugger to pinpoint where the bottleneck is located.

The code hangs at the following fragment:

```
        while(rs.next())
        {
            rows = new ArrayList();
            for(int columnCount = 1; columnCount <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); columnCount++)
            {
                Object fields = rs.getObject(columnCount);
                rows.add(fields);
            }
            table.add(rows);
            this.table = table;
        }
```

I use this method to make the information from the ResultSet more accessible for me.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Transactions? PreparedStatements?

Comment: It is too slow. Are your views too slow? Try to run queries directly in your DB.

Comment: Maybe your POC has a bad design, so its giving bad performance. Try to use a profiler to check the bottle necks in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Measure, isolate, improve.

All performance improvement goes through a cycle.  The problem is that you are measuring at a too high level, not isolating, and so you don't know what to improve.  Because of this lack of a work flow, you are searching for "possible problems" which might (or might not) apply to your situation.

How much of the time is in the application, and how much of the time is in the database?  How many requests does your application make?  Do those requests fall into categories?  Are any of them taking a significant amount of time?  Your application makes requests and processes the responses, is the most time spent making the requests, waiting for replies, or processing responses?

As soon as you have an idea of what is slowing down your application, then you know where to look.

And, queries don't commit.  Updates, inserts, and deletions commit.